# Is lataver.Controllers.Person is a type but is used as a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've got this MVC code:

```
<p><span data-bind="text: getName()" ></span></p>
```

This is basic.cshtml:

```
@section Scripts {

<script>
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = firstName + ' ' + surName;
        self.getName = function () {
            return self.name;
        };
        var viewModel = new ViewModel('@Model.firstName', '@Model.surName');
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    };
</script>

}
```

HomeController:

```
namespace latever.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Basic()
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                firstName = "Adam",
                surName = "Andersen"
            };
            return View(Person);
        }
    }
}
```

and my Person.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace latever.Controllers
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string surName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, It looks pretty simple, I'm just trying to somehow print out the name in basic.cshtml with use of ko.js, but appereantly it won't work with the `Person` class.

Comment: C# is case sensitive. _Person_ is not the same as _person_

Comment: JS: You call `ViewModel` with two arguments, but the function takes none.

Comment: @Jeroen Not only that, but my binding was in wrong place. Anyway I fixed it, thanks :D

Comment: Good to hear you got things working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. Person is not the same as person

```
public ActionResult Basic()
{
    var person = new Person
    {
        firstName = "Adam",
        surName = "Andersen"
    };
    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, how could I miss it. Anyway, tried to launch it and got another error 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.'